# Why brew never asks for a password?

Tags: macos, sudo, homebrew

I have been an Ubuntu user for the last 3 years and now I shifted to Mac OS X. I set my account to be an admin user, and have my own space at `/Users/<my-username>`.

Each time I used to install packages on my Ubuntu, it asked for my root password and I have to do it by prefixing it with `sudo`. But here in OS X, I can simply do a `brew install`. I understand I am a root user(have admin rights), so I don't need to use `sudo`, but for starting the services like `mongod`, I have to use `sudo`. Why so?

I am not getting it; can anybody explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew not only does not require `sudo`, but warns against using it.

Homebrew stores the files in the "user space" (under `/usr/local` branch) and does not touch the system directories.

Executable files are kept in `/usr/local/bin`, configuration files in `/usr/local/etc`, packages in `/usr/local/Cellar`. Neither of these directories require administrative permissions to write files (by default an owner and members of the group `admin` have full permissions to these directories).

On Ubuntu you are asked for administrative permissions, because packages installed by APT store their files and configuration in system directories (like `/etc`, `/usr/bin`) which by default do not allow being modified by a regular user.

On the other hand, if you run a program it might require administrative permissions to perform certain actions (like registering as a service). This requirement is separate from the rights to read/write files (belonging to the package) and in these cases both Ubuntu and Mac OS X require `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks, why does it warns against using it ?

Comment: @ankcodes Because it was designed to be run as a regular user. The problem is that if you use it once with `sudo`, then root account will own all newly created directories. If you then run it as a regular user, it won't be able to upgrade or delete old packages.

Comment: This helps a bit more, http://askubuntu.com/a/308048/340132 . Thanks :)